# How to handle null arguments in Getx Routing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-routes

So I'm Using `Getx`'s routing in Flutter.

I have a Product class that accepts an argument of the type `Product`

```
  const Produkt({
    required this.product,
  });
```

I handle the navigation through GetPages, like:

```
  GetPage(
    name: Produkt.route,
    page: () => Produkt(
      product: Get.arguments['product'],
    ),
  ),
```

But of course, this only works when the arguments aren't null. How could I redirect to an error page when the arguments are null?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a simple condition inside the `build()` method of your `Produkt` widget like this:

```
class Produkt extends StatelessWidget {
  const Produkt({
    super.key,
    required this.product,
  });
  final product;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (product == null) {
      return YourErrorScreenWidget();
    }
    return WidegtOfProdukt();
  }
}
```

now based on `product` value, you can implement a `YourErrorScreenWidget()` if it's null, and your specific `WidegtOfProdukt()` when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is that you can make a check in the constructor to navigate to another screen when it's null, otherwise it will just work fine

```
 class Produkt extends StatelessWidget {
  Produkt({
    super.key,
    required this.product,
  }) {
    if (product == null) {
      Get.off(YourErrorScreenWidget());
    }
  }
  final product;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidegtOfProdukt();
  }
}
```

Note: you could also call the `Get.off()` to navigate to another screen from the `build()` method, but I guess there is no point of getting inside the `build()` method since you're going to navigate anyway.